# iOS email disable automatic link on names

Tags: ios, email, newsletter

I just noticed that with the latest iOS software 11.2.6 on iPhone Mail App some singer names inside a HTML newsletter are automatic linked to spotlight overlay with iTunes, Siri and web search results.

Is it possible to disable this feature with a tag or some code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good description what you can do to prevent this automatic link-generation on iOS ...

https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices

The solution may be point 4 in the text talking about an attribute which is injected in the code of the original email.

```
<a href="#" x-apple-data-detectors="true">
```

You can disable the optical changes by adding your own styles.

```
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}
```